# How can I have a pingable IP but the wireess interface is unassociated?

Tags: linux, networking, wifi

I've been installing wireless networking support on a base image and have ran into something really strange.  Look closely at the output of ifconfig and iwconfig.  I have a valid dhcp assigned ip from my router thats pingable but the wireless adapter is unassociated!! It worked yesterday without this weirdness when I did the exact same steps, but today its doing something different.  Something weird is going on with wpa_supplicant.  I'm documenting every step that I take so its reproducible in case I get run over by a bus but I might have missed documenting a step last night ;)

This is what I did to install Realterk wireless usb support:

```
apt-get install firmware-realtek iw crda wireless-regdb wireless-tools wpasupplicant
```

This is the output of lsub after I plug in the adapter:

```
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 0bda:8178 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192CU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
```

And dmseg:

```
[ 1096.600195] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 13 using dwc_otg
[ 1096.701786] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8178
[ 1096.704348] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1096.706830] usb 1-1.3: Product: 802.11n WLAN Adapter
[ 1096.709223] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Realtek
[ 1096.711575] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
```

And ifconfig:

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:ef:11:00:bf
          inet addr:192.168.10.110  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:57 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1598 (1.5 KiB)  TX bytes:2224 (2.1 KiB)
```

And iwconfig:

```
wlan0     unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.417 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated
          Sensitivity:0/0
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant_wlan0.conf
metric 10

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant_wlan1.conf
metric 20
```

wpa_supplicant_wlan0:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
country=CA
update_config=1

network={
        ssid="myssid"
        psk="mypassword"
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

Comment: The kernel sees `802.11n`, the only thing that is displaying `unassociated` is `iwconfig`.  `iwconfig` was built with WEP in mind, I would not worry about its output on a WPA2 connection.  Do you have `iproute2` to check what `ip addr show` displays?

Comment: But yesterday the same steps starting from the same base produced a different result.  So I must not have documented an intermediate step.  Also, wlan0 will only get an IP address if i reboot the system.  If I do ifdown/ifup it doesn't receive a dhcp offer (usually) and if it does then wpa_supplicant throws an error, but wlan0 still gets the offered IP address.

Comment: That depends a lot on what configuration your system uses as a base (systemd?).  Modern distros are pretty much abandoning `ifconfig`/`ifdown`/`ifup` scripts because they had become a different flavour on each distro.  `iproute2` scripts/binaries are much more consistent.  And, moreover, i *believe* that almost every modern distro is now using systemd services (the ones with @ arguments) to boot and shutdown the network.